# How to deserialize an array of objects with type adapter with Gson?

Tags: java, serialization, gson

How to deserialize an array of objects with type adapter with Gson?

```
package tests;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class Try03 {

    public static class B {

        double value;

        public B() {
            this(0);
        }

        public B(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        void setValue(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

    public static class A {

        B[] values = new B[3];
        transient double sum;

        public A() {
            sum = 0;
        }

        void refresh() {
            sum = values[0].getValue() + values[1].getValue() + values[2].getValue();
        }

        A set(int index, B b) {
            if( values[index] != null ) {
                sum -= values[index].getValue();
            }
            values[index] = b;
            if( values[index] != null ) {
                sum += values[index].getValue();
            }
            return this;
        }

    }

    public static class Ades implements JsonDeserializer<A> {

        @Override
        public A deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

            JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();

            B[] values = context.deserialize(obj.get("values"), B[].class);

            A ans = new A();
            ans.values = values;
            ans.refresh();

            return ans;
        }

    }

    public static class Aadap extends TypeAdapter<A> {

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, A value) throws IOException {
        }

        @Override
        public A read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

            in.beginObject();

            if( !in.nextName().equals("values") ) {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }

            in.beginArray();

            // how to read elements of type B?

            in.endArray();

            in.endObject();

            A ans = new A();

            return ans;
        }

    }

    static String[] bsrc = {

            "{\n" + 
                    "\"value\": 12.0\n" + 
            "}",

            "{\n" + 
                    "\"value\": 10.0\n" + 
            "}",

            "{\n" + 
                    "\"value\": 7.0\n"  + 
            "}"


    };

    static String asrc = "{\n" +
          "\"values\": [\n" +
            "{\n" +
              "\"value\": 32.0\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
              "\"value\": 5.0\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
              "\"value\": 8.0\n" +
            "}\n" +
          "]\n" +
        "}";

    // works
    public static void main01() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0)
                .create();

        B b = new B();
        b.setValue(12);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(b));

    }

    // works
    public static void main02() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0)
                .create();

        B b = gson.fromJson(bsrc[0], B.class);

        System.out.println(b);

    }

    // works
    public static void main03() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0)
                .create();

        B[] b = { new B(32), new B(5), new B(8) };
        A a = new A();
        a.set(0, b[0]).set(1, b[1]).set(2, b[2]);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(a));

    }

    // works but does not initialize transient field
    public static void main04() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0)
                .create();

        A a = gson.fromJson(asrc, A.class);

        System.out.println(a);

    }


    // works and does initialize transient field
    // but does not use TypeAdapter
    public static void main05() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0)
                .registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new Ades())
                .create();

        A a = gson.fromJson(asrc, A.class);

        System.out.println(a);

    }

    // don't know how to write type adapter
    public static void main06() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0)
                .registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new Aadap())
                .create();

        A a = gson.fromJson(asrc, A.class);

        System.out.println(a);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // main01();
        // main02();
        // main03();
        // main04();
        // main05();
        main06();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you did?

Comment: I want to learn how to use `TypeAdapter` since it is recommended way.

Comment: What's wrong with what you did?

Comment: Sorry don't understand you. Are you a bot?

Comment: You posted code. What's wrong with it that you have to ask the question? The question you're asking is too broad and very use case dependent. You possibly don't need type adapters at all.

Comment: `main06` is not working in my code because I don't know how to implement `Aadap` class. Is type adapters API incomplete? It is impossible to deserialize `A` with type adapters, right?